# glutDisplayFunc() with pointer to memeber functions

Tags: c++11, opengl, freeglut, member-pointers

I have a C++ class that contains the draw function that I want to pass to glutDisplayFunc(). glutDisplayFunc takes a function pointer (void (*)() ) as its argument. I have tried :

```
    Model myModel(pathToTextures);
    //Model contains the Draw function that draws the vertices and the textures
    std::function<void(void)> myfunc=std::bind(&Mymodel::Draw,&modelna);

    glutDisplayFunc(myfunc);
```

the compiler cannot convert the std::function pointer to the required.
 how can I bypass this hurdle of member function pointer?

Comment: I have just tried another method but it doesn't work either:     glutDisplayFunc([&Mymodel]( ){Mymodel.Draw();})

Comment: It won't work, because lambdas aren't convertible to function pointers if they capture anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit) library could do that for you.